Yahoo Finance Stock Import with VBA Stopped Working
I use VBA to pull stock prices into excel. It stopped working yesterday (Sep 24, 2024).
The method required a CRUM that does not seem to exist anymore. When requesting CRUM, I get "e html> <ht", which isn't garbage. The code does not create error until later when it does not have any data to work with.
Does anyone now that the solution is? The code is below. Much appreciated!!
Max
Sub getCookieCrumb(crumb As String, cookie As String, validCookieCrumb As Boolean)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim str As String
    Dim crumbStartPos As Long
    Dim crumbEndPos As Long
    Dim objRequest
 
    validCookieCrumb = False
    
    'ask for a valid crumb 5 times

    For i = 0 To 5  'ask for a valid crumb 5 times
        Set objRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        With objRequest
            .Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1=1503558000&period2=1535094000&interval=1wk&filter=history&frequency=1wk", False
            .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
            .send
            .WaitForResponse (10)
            crumbStartPos = InStrRev(.ResponseText, """crumb"":""") + 9
            crumbEndPos = crumbStartPos + 11
            crumb = Mid(.ResponseText, crumbStartPos, crumbEndPos - crumbStartPos)
        End With
        
        If Len(crumb) = 11 Then 'a valid crumb is 11 characters long
            validCookieCrumb = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub


What arguments do you use when call getCookieCrumb Sub? Does the code raise an error? If so, what error on which code line? If not, what else is happening?

Use Yahoo V8 - Chart api to get the data in JSON format and parse it using Tim Hall's JSon Parser where there is a sample code for getting Yahoo historical data.

@FaneDuru, the code produces no errors until it gets to the point where it does not have the data to do the calculations. This code is kind of funky. It just needs to produce this CRUM to pass to a different Sub, which will use the CRUM to build API request for stock prices.

Looking to the Sub name, I supose that it deals with the cookiies. It looks that not existing... try manually opening the page and accept its request, then try again.

I think Yahoo just started requiring users to be actively logged-in to download historical prices. The error I see is The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
